# Team Foundation Server - Solution Bindings Gone Missing

Tags: visual-studio, binding, tfs

I got this problem with TFS, I connected to the wrong network and tried to open a solution and it gave the error: "cannot connect to tfs". Fine, I closed the solution, and I switched to the correct network and now it says "the solution appears to be under source control but the bindings are missing bla bla."

I check the Team Explorer tab, and it shows that it's connected, but the solution, the projects lost interest in tfs somehow.

When I say "Change Source Control" and try to "Bind" all of the projects, it asks to check out every project, but I don't want to deal with conflicts now, I need my currently checked-out files.

did anyone face this problem and solve it?

Comment: Can you try File>Source Control>Go Online? Does that give the same behavior?

Comment: But there's no option like that now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found a solution:

Right-click on solution and click "Add Solution To Source Control". Then it says something like "Are you sure? This project already seems to be under some source control", click "Ignore All" for everything that pops up. And viola, your bindings are magically back in order. I really don't know why, or how. it just happened.

But this operation might checkout your solution file if it's not checked out already.

Comment: Doing "Add Solution to Source control" is checking out all projects under the solution. If i do undo pending changes it removing from TFS ,I mean its become offline. I created work space and ran the soulution from local folder then I did not see it online. Hence I did "Add solution....". Please let me know the solution